# Substituir o If/else por Case javascript

Tags: javascript, condição, matriz

Gostaria de substituir o if/else por Case pois acredito que vai ser melhor para entendimento do código já que ele vai ficar um pouco longo, porém não consigo acessar a Array que vai ter as condições para ativar as ações. O Erro está no código ou na lógica?

ex:

```
window.onscroll = function animaMenu() {
    var menu = [pageYOffset > 70 , pageYOffset > 800 ];
    switch (menu) {
        case 0:
            var x = document.getElementById("nav").className = "navegacao-movel"
        break
        case 1:
            var x = document.getElementById("ball").className = "movimento"
            alert("teste")
        break
    }
}
window.onload = animaMenu();
```

Esse codigo é o que pretendo alterar

```
window.onscroll = function animaMenu() {
    if (pageYOffset > 70) {
          document.getElementById("nav").className = "navegacao-movel"

    } else if (pageYOffset > 800) {
          document.getElementById("nav").className = "navegacao"        

    } else if (pageYOffset > 1600) {
          document.getElementById("section").className = "hover"        
    }
}
window.onload = animaMenu();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você está fazendo um `switch` em uma lista, creio que ele só se aplica a um valor primitivo. Além disso, JavaScript usa `true` e `false` para valores booleanos, não `0` e `1`.

Entretanto, há uma maneira de se colocar suas condições `true`/`false` num array e fazer um `switch` na primeira delas que se aplica. O único detalhe é que, no seu caso, isso tem de ser feito de trás pra frente (pois há uma hierarquia de condições - se `X > 800` então `X > 70`, então você tem que testar os maiores primeiro).

```
var menu = [pageXOffset > 1600, pageXOffset > 800, pageXOffset > 70];
switch (menu.indexOf(true)) {
    case 0:
        var x = document.getElementById("nav").className = "hover"
    break
    case 1:
        var x = document.getElementById("nav").className = "movimento"
    break
    case 2:
        var x = document.getElementById("nav").className = "navegacao-movel"
    break
}
```

A função `indexOf` da classe `Array` pega o primeiro índice na qual um elemento é encontrado. Se você tem então um array de booleans, basta procurar nesse array por `true`.

Comment: Eu pensei que usando Numero no caso do exemplo eu pegaria a posição do Array e com isso o calculo da condição, vou testar sua resposta.

Comment: @HeltonSS hm, entendi, mas de fato não é assim que o `switch` funciona. Mas talvez seja possível fazer algo como o que você quer usando uma biblioteca de bitset. Vou fazer uma pesquisa rápida, se tiver resultado volto aqui.

Comment: com certeza a decisão de if é melhor e mais limpa, acreditei que com case deixaria mais legível usando array, mas meu tempo não me deixa fazer uma pesquisa mais ampla, mesmo assim muito obrigado.

Comment: @HeltonSS Atualizei minha resposta. Dá pra fazer isso usando uma função nativa do `Array`.

Comment: Fantástico eu sabia que eu não era tão louco rsrs, mas não imaginava da necessidade da indexof não pensaria nisso tão cedo, Obrigado de novo e funcionou corretamente.

pg: não é  pageXOffset é pageYOffset acho que errei na hora de digitar a pergunta.

Answer (score 4):

No seu caso, para facilitar o entendimento e diminuir as linhas de código, não é necessário `switch(case)` nem `if&else`, você pode apenas utilizar `Array`'s como demonstrou parte da resposta do **@mgibsonbr**(array de condicoes), porém eu não vejo porque utilizar `switch(case)`:

```
var values = ["navegacao-movel","navegacao","hover"];
var cond   = [pageYOffset > 1600, pageYOffset > 800, pageYOffset > 70];
document.getElementById("nav").className = values[cond.indexOf(true)];
```

Desta forma você pode até adicionar mais condições e valores, se quiser.

Comment: realmente a solução também é boa, o fato de ter escolhido o case foi ter uma linha de raciocinio e seguir ela. mas ficou muito bom.

Comment: Como assim, ter uma linha de raciocínio? você não consegue ter uma desta forma? - arrumei o pageYOffset como você falou em comentário.

Comment: Realmente gostaria de saber o motivo do Downvote, Downvoter. O que há de errado com minha resposta?

Comment: +1 nesse caso onde o código é homogêneo (só muda um valor, mas mesmo que mudasse dois ou três) essa solução é melhor. Só num caso heterogêneo (ex.: onde o código é radicalmente diferente conforme a condição) que se justifica usar um `switch`.

Answer (score 2):

Quando você coloc o `else if` você terá que colocar uma nova condição. Por exemplo:

```
   else if( x > y) { };
```

Porém no ultimo termo, na ultima condição deve ser um `else` que corresponde dizer que nenhuma condiçoes anteriores funtionou:. Por Exemplo:

```
  if(x == y){
      // verficação 1
  }else if(x < y){
      // verficação 2
  }else if(x > y){
      // verficação 3
  }else{
      // Nenhuma das condições funcionou então ... 
  }
```

Espero ter ajudado. Abraço.

Comment: -1 Nesse caso você deveria usar o `default:`

Comment: Eu apenas mostrei um erro no código que não usa o `switch`, mas sim o `if/else`, tanto que a pergunta foi editada, mas sua obsevarção no seu ponto de vista está correta.

Answer (score 2):

Pessoalmente não gosto muito de switch/case. Sintaxe feia e fácil de cometer erros. Uma opção a ser considerada é usar um vetor. Segue um pseudocódigo (não testado):

```
opcoes = {};
opcoes["1"] = function() { faz_isso(); };
opcoes["2"] = function() { faz_aquilo(); };
opcoes["3"] = function() { faz_outro(); };

opcao = "" + menu; // converter para string

if (menu in opcoes) {
   // executa opção
   opcoes[menu]();
} else {
   // equivalente ao "default:" do switch/case
}
```

Comment: A sugestão é boa, mas na forma como está não é diretamente aplicável ao código do OP. Além disso não há vetor algum na sua solução, apenas um objeto comum.

Comment: @mgibsonbr `Uma opção a ser considerada é usar um vetor`. Pode ser considerada, mas não necessariamente :P

Comment: @epx É muito codigo estava procurando algo mais legivel e facil entendimento. mesmo assim grato.

Answer (score 0):

Levando em consideração que você quer alterar o valor desse elemento
`document.getElementById("nav").className`

eu usaria da seguinte forma:

```
document.getElementById("nav").className = (pageXOffset > 1600) ? "hover": ( (pageXOffset > 800)? "movimento":"navegacao-movel" );
```

Basicamente é um `IF` de uma linha e funciona da seguinte forma

```
CONDIÇÃO ? VERDADEIRO : FALSO
```

no exemplo eu usei 2

```
CONDIÇÃO ? VERDADEIRO : ( CONDIÇÃO ? VERDADEIRO : FALSO )
```

Comment: Não se adapta ao código do OP, pois você simplesmente não utilizou a condição `(PageXOffset > 70)`, e também, acredito que esta solução, apesar de ser feita em apenas uma linha, não é de fácil entendimento pra quem olha.